# Leetcode "Binary Tree Preorder Traversal" issue

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree

I'm trying to solve trivial binary tree preorder traversal problem from [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/data-structure-tree/134/traverse-a-tree/928/).
Here is my solution:

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution:
     def preorderTraversal(self, root: TreeNode, node_list = []) -> List[int]:
        if not root:
            return []
        
        node_list.append(root.val)
        for leaf in (root.left, root.right):
            if leaf is not None:
                self.preorderTraversal(leaf, node_list)
        return node_list
```

but it don't pass following testcase:

```
Input: [1]
Output: [1,2,3,1]
Expected: [1]
```

How can it be possible to get output `[1,2,3,1]` from one single node which has no leafs at all. For me, it should add value of the first node (`1`) to the values list, iteratively check children-nodes (both of them should be `None`) and return node-values list, (which consist of the only not-None value from the first node - `[1]`). From where it gets 2,3,1 values if the tree consists form one single node: `val = 1, left = None, right = None`?
I am definitely missing something obvious, but cannot figure out what exactly. Please help me out.

Comment: Your problem is the `node_list = []`.  Every call to `preorderTraversal` is going to be using the exact same list.  The `[1, 2, 3]` is probably left over from the previous call to this method.  This is a well-known gotcha in Python, and one of the reasons you must never default initialize a variable to a list.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: I would suggest that you change your code to use a helper method that does nothing bug appends items to a list passed to it as an argument.  It will be recursive.  Then `preorderTraversal(node)` does `lst = [];  helper(node, lst); return lst`

Comment: @FrankYellin thank you. It's not the first time I got caught on default argument initialization. I just didn't think of it, because I was looking towards the algorithm, not of the language peculiarities  .

Answer (score 0):

As Frank Yellin noted in the comments the problem is with the default list to the function.

Here's a version that works:

```py
class Solution:

    def preorderTraversal(self, root: TreeNode) -> List[int]:
        return self.helper(root, [])
            
    def helper(self, node, node_list): 
        if not node:
            return []
        
        node_list.append(node.val)
        for leaf in (node.left, node.right):
            if leaf is not None:
                self.helper(leaf, node_list)
        return node_list
```

The code is all yours. I just created a helper function with the meat of the algorithm taken out of the main function.